# How to convert Shared VB.NET method to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, static, porting, shared

I have the following method written in VB.NET:

```
Public Shared Function formatClassNameAndMethod(ByVal prefix As String, ByVal stackFrame As StackFrame) As String

        Dim methodBase As MethodBase = StackFrame.GetMethod()

        Return prefix + ":[" + stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace + "][" + stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name + "." + methodBase.Name + "] "

End Function
```

I used a code porting tool to convert it to C#.  It produced the following method:

```
public static string formatClassNameAndMethod(string prefix, StackFrame stackFrame)
{
    MethodBase methodBase = StackFrame.GetMethod();

    return prefix + ":[" + stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace + "][" + 
            stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name + "." + methodBase.Name + "] ";
}
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio now gives me the following error:

> Cannot access non-static method 'GetMethod' in static context

It is complaining about `StackFrame.GetMethod()` because that method is not static.  Why is this happening?  I understand what the error is, but I don't understand why I didn't get this in VB.NET.  Is there a difference between how Shared in VB.NET and static in C# work?  Did the conversion tool not properly convert this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB is case-insensitive - the compiler saw "StackFrame.GetMethod()" and said "Oh, the developer must have meant "stackFrame.GetMethod()".

Answer (score 8):

`GetMethod` isn't static. This is what it is telling you.

This means you need to create an instance before you can call the method. Your method already has a `StackFrame` instance passed in.. and this is merely a case of case sensitivity. Lowercase the *S*.

```
public static string formatClassNameAndMethod(string prefix, StackFrame stackFrame)
{ //                                                                     ^^^ this
    MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
    //                     ^^ lowercase S
```

Comment: I understand how to solve the problem from that perspective.  My interest lies more in why it worked in VB.NET and not C#.

Comment: This is a great reason why you should not name your parameter the same as your class name, even if different by case.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Ok, that makes it much clearer for me.  I think I copied this code from another SO question and didn't really pay too much attention to the parameter names.  You learn something new every day.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas If you move your comment into an answer I'll accept it, because technically your answer is most relevant to my question.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Good call.  That was also a good reason to not just copy code without fully reviewing it!